# Parse words separate by |

Tags: java, regex, parsing, grammar

I have a string #`JSGF V1.0;grammar numbers;public <accion> = (one| two| three);`
I want the numbers: one, two and three.

I did this `String answer = res.substring(res.indexOf("(")+1,res.indexOf(")"));` and obtain `one| two| three`, but Im having trouble in this part.

Ideas?

Comment: Take your String `answer` and use a RegEx on it.

Comment: did you mean `answer.split("\\s*\\|\\s*")`

Comment: Use Matcher and `\((.*?\|)+\)`

Comment: Maybe helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986543/replicating-string-split-with-stringtokenizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split the `answer` on non-word characters:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String res = "JSGF V1.0;grammar numbers;public <accion> = (one| two| three);";
    String answer = res.substring(res.indexOf("(") + 1, res.indexOf(")"));
    String[] numbers = answer.split("[^\\w]+"); // split on non-word character
    for (String number : numbers) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

output:

```
one
two
three
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the numbers as array using

```
String numbers[] = answer.split("\\s*\\|\\s*");
```

`\\s*\\|\\s*`: 0 or more spaces then `|` symbol and 0 or more spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
String res = "(one| two| three);";
String answer = res.substring(res.indexOf("(")+1,res.indexOf(")"));
for(String str : answer.split("\\s*\\|\\s*")) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```